# How to pass Main class reference to JFrame class

Tags: java, swing

How would I go about passing on the main class reference to my JFrame class. I want to use a function inside my Main class in my JFrame class and vice-versa. I want to use the function addOne() from my Main class inside my JFrame class and the function getNumber() from the JFrame class in my Main class.

I've tried the code below and get the error "The constructor MyJFrame(new Runnable(){}) is undefined" when I try to pass the Main class reference.

Code :

```
package main;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    
    public MyJFrame myJFrame;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                this.myJFrame = new MyJFrame(this);
            }
        });
    }

    public int addOne(int amount)
    {
        //i want to use the method getNumber from the MyJFrame class here
        return amount + 1;
    }
    
}
```

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2422522191234311369L;
    
    Main main;
    
    public MyJFrame(Main main)
    {
        super("MyJFrame");
        this.main = main;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        addWindowListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been activated");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("About to close window");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been deactivated");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been restored"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been minimized");
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window has been opened");
    }
    
    //i want to use this function inside my Main class
    public int getNumber() 
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I tried to create an instance of MyJFrame in the Main class and pass the main class reference in the parameters but this did not work.

`public MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame(this);`

Comment: Well, which instance of `Main` do you want to pass as a reference to the `MyJFrame` constructor? (Hint: at the moment, I don't see any instances of `Main` being created...) Also, "this did not work" is never enough information - *always* show the exact error (or whatever the undesirable behavior is) and explain how you've attempted to fix it, or what you don't understand about it.

Comment: hint: find out the difference between static and non-static methods.

Comment: I've updated the code to what I've last tried. I've read the Java classes reference each other post but unfortunately I did not manage to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... How would I go about passing on the main class reference to my JFrame class. ..."*

You won't need to pass the instance to *MyJFrame*.

```java
public MyJFrame()
{
    super("MyJFrame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(this);
}
```

And, instantiate *Main* since you're looking to access it from within the *invokeLater* *closure*.

```java
Main main = new Main();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> main.myJFrame = new MyJFrame());
```

```java
public int addOne(int amount)
{
    return myJFrame.getNumber();
}
```

Comment: I implemented this into my program and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyFrame` looks ok - you can pass an instance of Main to the constructor, and that even gets stored into the instance variable `main`.

In `main.Main.main()` however you have these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            this.myJFrame = new MyJFrame(this);
        }
    });
}
```

The compiler should actually refuse to compile. When resolving `this`, the only instance available is the anonymous runnable you created using `new Runnable()`, which is not derived from Main.

On top of that Java runs the `public static void main(...)` method without creating any instance of `Main`, so you have nothing that you can refer to.

Therefore, change the one line into something like

```
this.myJFrame = new MyJFrame(new Main());
```

and it should compile. Whether that does what you need is still up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added "Main main = new Main();" to my main method. I pass this reference runnable like this "MyJFrame myFrame = new MyJFrame(main);" It does compile now, but unfortunately I get NullPointers when I use the class methods because the instances are still incorrect. Here is my new Main class https://pastebin.com/eSehNMC0